# Ant javac task errs out: [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6

Tags: java, ant, axis, javac

I'm trying to run an ant task that uses `axis2-ant-plugin-1.6.0.jar\org\apache\axis2\tool\ant\AntCodegenTask` to perform a `WSDL2Java` operation.

At the top of the ant script, I define `java6.boot.classpath`:

```
    <property name="java6.boot.classpath" value="${env.JAVA6_BOOT_CLASSES}"/>
```

And I have the `JAVA6_BOOT_CLASSES` environment variable set to `C:\dev\java\64-bit\jdk-1.6.0_45\bin`.

The pertinent ant target is as follows:

```
<!-- dist.jar target -->
<target name="dist.jar" depends="generate"
    description="Creates the web services client jar file">
    <echo>Compiling web services client code</echo>

    <javac srcdir="${project.javapath}" destdir="${build}" 
           source="1.6" target="1.6" 
           debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" 
           excludes="com/company/junit/**"
           bootclasspath="${java6.boot.classpath}"
           includeantruntime="false">

        <classpath refid="compile.classpath" />
    </javac>

    <echo>Creating ${jarname}.jar</echo>
    <jar destfile="${dist}/${jarname}.jar" basedir="${build}" />
    <echo>${jarname}.jar created</echo>
</target>
```

Trying to run that, however, I receive the titular error:

```
 [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
```

Any ideas?  I feel like I've appropriately set the boot classpath for Java 1.6, but ant doesn't seem to agree.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not Ant but the JDK's javac emitting the warning.

If you use Java 7's javac and -source for anything smaller than 7 javac warns you you should also set the bootstrap classpath to point to an older rt.jar - because this is the only way to ensure the result is usable on an older VM.

https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/bootclasspath_older_source

This is only a warning, so you could ignore it  and even suppress it with

```
<compilerarg value="-Xlint:-options"/>
```

Alternatively you really install an older JVM and adapt your bootclasspath accordingly (you need to include `rt.jar`, not the `bin` folder)

Comment: so if i change my java6 env variable to point to jdk1.6's `lib` folder, would that be good enough?  the way i read the script is that i'm explicitly telling it to use my java6 jdk by supplying the `bootclasspath` argument...

Comment: It would need to point directly at `rt.jar` or use a wildcard `lib/*.jar`.

Answer (score 5):

In the ant `build.xml` file create a property which will point to Java 6 `rt.jar`

`<path id="boot.classpath" location="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/lib/rt.jar" />`

and refer to it in the `javac` task:

`<javac srcdir="${src}" bootclasspathref="boot.classpath" classpathref="classpath" includeantruntime="false" destdir="${build}" source="1.6" target="1.6" />`

You may also directly specify the bootclasspath in `javac` task using `bootclasspath` attribute

Answer (score 2):

> And I have the JAVA6_BOOT_CLASSES environment variable set to
>   C:\dev\java\64-bit\jdk-1.6.0_45\bin.

This is the problem. Set the bootclasspath to point to the directory that contains the rt.jar. It should be like: C:\dev\java\64-bit\jdk-1.6.0_45\jre\lib