# Generate jar for java 6 target using java 8 with ant

Tags: java, ant, jar

I am using java 8 with ant to generate the jar file for a library I have written. There are no lambdas being used in the project and I want to generate a jar compatible with java 6.

I've edited the following lines in my build file

```
<property name="target" value="1.8"/>
<property name="source" value="1.8"/>
```

an replaced it with

```
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
```

to rebuild and generate the jar. It throws a warning telling  `warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6`

Is this the right way to generate the compatible jar using java 8 ? I am curious about how this really works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That warning can be ignored.  It is warning you that you might accidentally use Java 1.8 APIs even when compiling for Java 1.6.

To compile against the Java 1.6 APIs (getting more assurance of compatibility), you have some more work to do.  See:

[Ant javac task errs out: [javac] warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287383/ant-javac-task-errs-out-javac-warning-options-bootstrap-class-path-not-set)